# how to merge three tables together on mySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

So I can create three individual scripts to successfully pull out the data I want from each table I have in my database.

```
SELECT StreetID, StreetName, City, State, StreetType FROM streetinfo;
SELECT Date, Street, Total_Drives FROM drives WHERE Date >= '2001-10-01' AND Date <= '2020-03-26';
SELECT EVENT_LCL_DATE, EVENT_STRT_ID, COUNT(Street_Accidents) Total_Accidents FROM accidents GROUP BY EVENT_LCL_DATE;
```

Now I want to generate a table with the following column names...

```
EventDate, StreetID, StreetName, City, State, StreetType, Total_Drives, Total_Accidents, Accident_Rate
```

...by merging them together with the following script.

```
SELECT
    d.Date EventDate
    d.Facility FacilityID
    as.FacilityName
    as.City
    as.State
    d.Total_Drives
    as.Total_Accidents
    as.Total_Accidents/d.Total_Drives*100000 Accident_Rate
FROM drives d
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT a.EVENT_LCL_DATE EventDate, a.EVENT_STRT_ID StreetID, s.FacilityName, s.City, s.State, s.Label, COUNT(*) Total_Accidents
        FROM accidents a
        INNER JOIN streettinfo s ON s.StreetID = s.EVENT_STRT_ID;
        ) as
        ON as.EventDate = d.Date AND as.StreetID=d.Facility
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

However, the last time I ran this query, only the EventDate, Facility, and Total_Drives columns were filled with data. I have tried to inner join the d and as tables, but that led to one row of data when I am expecting as many rows as the d table provides. Are there any suggestions as to how to get the table exactly the way I want it? Any assistance is truly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please point out the relationship between these three tables? Say primary key, foreign key etc

Comment: could you please provide sample data of your table

Comment: You aren't aggregating in the main query so you should not be using group by. The query will not fail but the results will likely be non determinate. and the sub query has an aggregate function with no group by so the result will be over the entire dataset. I see your 3rd query does so - why did you drop the group by?

Comment: Your query is malformed.  It has a `group by` but there are lots of unaggregated columns in the `select`.  That is not allowed (under most circumstances) in the most recent versions of MySQL.